# image not displayed correctly when scaled with a decimal

Tags: python, opencv, numpy

I am using OpenCV to read and display an image. I am trying to do a scalar multiplication but it is being displayed very differently for two similar approaches:

```
img = cv2.imread('C:/Python27/user_scripts/images/g1.jpg', -1)
cv2.imshow('img_scaled1', 0.5*img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.imshow('img_scaled2', img/2)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

In the 1st case, hardly anything is displayed. 2nd case works fine.
It seems to me that `imshow()` does not support numpy array of floats.

I want to use the first method. Can somebody help?

Comment: Often such problem is a type issue. Can `imshow((im*.5).astype(uint8))` resolve it ?

Comment: @B.M. that worked with a minor change, `imshow((im*.5).astype('uint8'))`
resolved it. Thanks!

Comment: @B.M. You should submit that as an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are lot of pitfall when using images. This one seems like a type issue.

`imshow`accept `uint8` arrays  in range(0,256) (256 excluded), and `float` arrays  in range(0.0,1.0).  When doing `a=a*.5`, you have a float array out of range, so no warranty on the result.

A solution is to cast the array in the `uint8` type by:

```
imshow((a*.5).astype(np.uint8))
```

or

```
imshow((a*.5).astype('uint8'))
```